Применить стили к блоку при условии, что внутри присутствует определенный класс
Возможно ли в CSS применить стили к блоку в том случае, если в дочерних элементах присутствует определенный класс?

.block:has(.class) {}

А если применить стили к блоку в том случаи если во всем документе будет присутствовать определенный класс?

.block:has(.class) {} работает, необходимо соблюдать последовательность вложений

Стоит заметить, что :has имеет довольно плохую поддержку (хотя... 91%, не знаю даже)

@Алекс, > А если применить стили к блоку в том случаи если во всем документе будет присутствовать определенный класс? :root:has(.tut_triggers_class) :is(.good, .blocks, .for, .us) {}
